# Приложение ,загруженное с Google Play, перестало работать

Tags: android, google-play

Реализовал аутентификацию через Google. Опубликовал в тестовом режиме в консоли разработчика. В Android Studio на эмуляторе и на реальном устройстве всё работает корректно, а вот приложение ,загруженное с Google Play не входит в аккаунт. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно же проблема с ключами. поменяй key на release в акк гугла

Comment: Вы имеете в виду поменять SHA-1? Для release нужен другой ключ?

Comment: Да именно так..

Comment: Спасибо, Вы были правы! Правда, этот проект уже не принимает обновления с этим ключом, и нельзя приложение удалить с консоли,придётся пересоздавать проект заново!